# Read xml in infopath using javascript

Tags: javascript, infopath, jquery

I want to read xml inside the infopath form. I am saving all infopath forms after submitting into a form library. Now I want to read the xml inside that. I am doing like following,

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/sites/mysite/DemandRequests/DR_37.xml",
        contentType:'xml',
        success:function(xmlContent){
            console.log(xmlContent);
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
});
```

Content is coming as pure html. I am not finding any xml init. How to read only xml?

Comment: Can you post the value that is coming in object `xmlContent`

Comment: It is coming as very big html. Entire page is coming

Comment: Yes post the relevant.. basically where the xml data is inside the entire html?

Comment: There is no xml. output is coming as tables, that means xml was converted into the html

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/sites/mysite/DemandRequests/DR_37.xml?NoRedirect=true',
        datatype: 'xml',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success:function(xmlContent){
            console.log(xmlContent);
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me.  The key part is the NoRedirect.  Thanks.